# JS regex check string for allowed words only?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if string only contains allowed keywords and *space*, i.e.

```
var str = "foo bar baz"
```

String can be `baz`, `foo bar`, `baz foo`, etc, but should **only** contain *those 3 words* and a *space*.

Comment: I currently use `indexOf()` but it feels really dirty to me and I'm dumb at regexps

Comment: Should leading/trailing spaces be allowed?  i.e. `foo bar ` ?

Comment: Also, can there be multiple consecutive spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(foo|bar|baz)( (foo|bar|baz))*$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1xG5/1)

---

- `^$` - starting from the beginning til the end
- `(foo|bar|baz)` - have at least one of `foo`, `bar` or `baz`
- `( (foo|bar|baz))*` - followed by zero or more times *space* and one of `foo`, `bar` or `baz`